# php single function with multiple names / aliases

Tags: php

This isn't really important but the question is more one of curiosity.

Is it possible to alias a function or define two names for it.

I know this works:

```
function real($p1=array(), $p2=null, $p3='default'){
  return 'something';
}

function aliasForReal($p1=array(), $p2=null, $p3='default'){
  return real($p1, $p2, $p3);
}
```

Is there a less verbose way to alias another function?

something like

```
function (real||aliasForReal)(...){
```

or

```
function aliasForReal extends real;
```

There are a couple of places I need to do this and the working method above just feels a bit dirty to me.

For instance:

using names like **(begin and start)** interchangeably for one function and **(end and stop)** for another.

Comment: Note that it *is* possible to do this starting from PHP 5.6 (which is currently in beta). I have added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23426311/50079) to the dupe.

Comment: Yes, is duplicate, just found that question after I posted

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't see the other question.

Answer (score -1):

```
function real($p1=array(), $p2=null, $p3='default'){
  return 'something';
}

$real1 = 'real';
$real2 = 'real';
// etc
```

You can call $real1(...)

Answer (score -1):

```
function real(){
    return "real";
}

function realAlias(){
    return "realAlias";
}

$p = "real";
print $p();

$p = "realAlias";
print $p();
```

does it help?