# Php, include 2 files with functions "cannot redeclare"

Tags: php, wordpress, function, mybb

I have two systems in my websites: Wordpress and myBB forum.
I want to connect them, everyone who register in wordpress (my main site) will be registered in myBB.

I started to write plugin that will be bridge. and i have the global file of myBB, when I include this file i see this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_attachment_icon() ...

Now, how can I include the file but keep the functions seperate? can I include the functions into namespace or variable?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You could wrap them in a class

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Create a class and turn this functions in static methods
2. Rewrite the name of the functions and refactor the code
3. Or you can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23426311/1906372

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there are to many functions to disable.there is a way to include function into class or namespace?? I

Answer (score 0):

Is the function `get_attachment_icon` really declared in both WP and MyBB? It seems unlikely somehow.

If it is in a single file, then that file has to be included or required with `include_once` or `require_once`, not with `include` or `require`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but yes. I tried to disable the function but there are more functions that redeclared. there is a way to include function into class or namespace?? I must both files..

Comment: First you need to understand *what is happening*. So: you have **two files** and the same function with the same name is in both? What are the file names? Can you include **the full text of the error with file names and line numbers**?